# .NET CORE web api Changes not detected

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm currently working on a VueJS app using .NET Core 2.2 for the back-end part.
I was working on it for a few months but it suddenly stopped working like a charm when I updated from 2.0 to 2.2.

My web API changes are not detected and I don't know why.
For instance, I have a few controllers and whenever I change them, and then use the web API, the changes are not made. I can even delete the whole file and the web API using this file will still be working!

Another problem I get is that when I create new controller files, it's not detected; I'm stuck with my old controllers, which I'm not able to update.
Others files updates are detected (at least if I change the VueJS front-end)
I can also change the providers, delete whatever file used for the web API, changes are not detected. It may be a configuration issue?

Is there anything I could try to make things update again?

Update: I can change whatever I want in the back-end and it will do nothing. Compilations errors are the only problem I have to care about, it's like the app doesn't use the code anymore.

Here is an example I can provide:

I have a controller `InterventionController` which retrieve data about operations (I am french in a french context so variables names, etc will be in french) :

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Vue2Spa.Models;
using Vue2Spa.Providers;

namespace Vue2Spa.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InterventionController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IInterventionProvider interventionProvider;


        public InterventionController(IInterventionProvider interventionProvider)
        {
            this.interventionProvider = interventionProvider;
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Interventions([FromQuery(Name = "from")] int from = 0, [FromQuery(Name = "to")] int to = 5000)
        {

            var quantity = to - from;

            if (quantity <= 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("La quantité doit être positive !");
            }
            else if (from < 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("Vous devez spécifier un indice de départ non nul !");
            }

            var allInterventions = interventionProvider.GetInterventions();

            var result = new
            {
                TotalInterventions = allInterventions.Count,
                Interventions = allInterventions.Skip(from).Take(quantity).ToArray()       
            };

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }

    // Others methods not useful for my example
}
```

It calls a provider which has the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Vue2Spa.Models;

namespace Vue2Spa.Providers
{
    public class DBInterventionProvider : IInterventionProvider
    {

        private List<Intervention> interventions { get; set; }
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<DepouillementTestContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DepouillementTestContext>();

        public DBInterventionProvider()
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(credentials); // Credentials are correct but not including it there for obvious reasons
            using (var context = new LECESDepouillementTestContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                interventions = context.Intervention.ToList();
            }
        }

        public List<Intervention> GetInterventions()
        {
            using (var context = new LECESDepouillementTestContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                interventions = context.Intervention.ToList();
            }
            return interventions;
        }

    // Others methods not useful for this example

    }
}
```

I can delete these files, and I'm still able to access my operations web API

If needed, here is my startup.cs file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Vue2Spa.Models;

namespace Vue2Spa
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            // Additional code for SQL connection

            services.AddDbContext<DepouillementTestContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"],
                sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                {
                    sqlOptions.
                        MigrationsAssembly(
                            typeof(Startup).
                            GetTypeInfo().
                                Assembly.
                                GetName().Name);

                    //Configuring Connection Resiliency:
                    sqlOptions.
                        EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5,
                        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                        errorNumbersToAdd: null);

                });

                // Changing default behavior when client evaluation occurs to throw.
                // Default in EFCore would be to log warning when client evaluation is done.
                options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(
                    RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
            });

            // Provider pour les interventions
            services.AddSingleton<Providers.IInterventionProvider, Providers.DBInterventionProvider>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                // Webpack initialization with hot-reload.
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
                {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true,
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: *I have a few controllers and whenever I change them, and then use the web api, the changes are not made.* - do you mean when you make a code change and run the application then the web api running on localhost is unchanged? Or are you talking to a staging server not running on localhost? And: how are you testing this, are you calling the API with something like Postman, or are you using the vue.js website to test?

Comment: It's running on localhost, and when I make a code change and run the application, there is no change on the web api. I've tested it through Postman and directly from the vue.js website and the problem happens in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've found why I had this problem, and I feel kinda dumb for that but well, it's working now.

I didn't change my launch.json when I upgraded from .NETCORE 2.0 to 2.2, all I had to do was changing

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/content/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Vue2Spa.dll",
```

by

```
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/content/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Vue2Spa.dll",
```

For more informations, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio